# how to save list of different sized lists into dataframe or other datastructure in R

Tags: r, list, data-structures

I am new to R, i have many list of  different sized lists, how can i save them in a data structure so that later on i could iterate over them. I think it is doable using data-frames if lists are of same size.
Assume you have 10 of such [  [ [ ],[ ],[ ] ] , [ [ ],[ ],[ ],[ ] ] , [ [ ],[ ] ] ] how to put all 10 in a single referenced variable

i hope this sample code clarifies it:

```
max=sample(1:10,6,replace=F)

for (n in 1:5){
  neighborList=list()

  for ( i in 1:max[n]){
    num=sample(15:49,20,replace=F) 
    neighborList[i] = 0

    for (j in 1:num[i])
    {
      neighborList[[i]][j] = i*j
    }
  }
}
```

each iteration of n, the sample code will create a different list of lists, i want to save by append them after each iteration, and use it for later. For example if variable temp saves all the list of lists generated , if possible i could say x[1] it should give me the first neighborList that was generated when n=1.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you have a list of lists it is already a data structure you can iterate over. So I don't understand your question.

Comment: There isn't enough information here to be able to help you. You need to provide a specific example and explain exactly what you intend to do while iterating over the lists.

Comment: sorry for being unclear i hope this helps . Assume you have 10 of such [ [[],[],[]] ,  [[],[],[],[]] , [[],[]] ] how to put all 10 in a single referenced variable, is it clear, or i am confusing you more

Comment: Consider using `lapply()` or `ldply()`

Comment: As Joeran said: consider posting a [reproducible example](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Reproducibility.html) and what the result should look like. Then you'll get answers.

Comment: @lukeA is it clear,  or there is something missing

Comment: For all who likes to down vote questions, at least give one day time for editing before down voting the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
max=sample(1:10,6,replace=F)

temp <- list()
for (n in 1:5){
  neighborList=list()

  for ( i in 1:max[n]){
    num=sample(15:49,20,replace=F) 
    neighborList[i] = 0

    for (j in 1:num[i])
    {
      neighborList[[i]][j] = i*j
    }
  }
  temp[[n]] <- neighborList
}
```

Doesn't `temp[[1]]` or `temp[1]` already give you what you want, i.e. the first neighborList that was generated when n=1?

Comment: such a obvious answer, i guess i am new to R. Thanks